# console throws an error that a variable is undefined just after console.log prints the contents of that variable

Tags: javascript, function, minimax

I tried to create a tic-tac-toe game using minimax algorithm. But before I could write the whole algorithm, I encountered an absurd type of error. This code is for reference in case if you have to look into the full code.

```js
//Using minimax to the same code of tictactoe2.js
$ = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

// adding click event to all boxes
$.forEach((element)=>{
    element.addEventListener("click", mainFunction);
})

document.querySelector(".reset-button-container").addEventListener("click", reset);

function mainFunction(e){
    if (checkForGameOver() === false){ //once game is over, so should be all clicks
        if (e.target.innerText !== ""){
            alert("Click Another Square!!!");
        }
        else{
            e.target.innerText = "X";
            if (checkForGameOver() === false){ //computer gets its turn only if the game isn't over after players turn
                setTimeout(computerTurn, 500);
                setTimeout(checkForGameOver, 501); //501 is provided to run checkForGameOver only after computerTurn
            }
        }
    }
}

//a function that randomly plays computers turn
function computerTurn(){
    let board = [], bestScore = Infinity, bestMove = {}, k = 0;
    //array of innerTexts of each box is the board in one dimension
    $.forEach((element, index) => {
        board[index] = element.innerText;
    });

    let board2D = convertToTwoDimension(board, 3, 3); //convert 1d board to 2d of 3 rows and 3 columns
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if (board2D[i][j] === ""){
                board2D[i][j] = "O";
                let score = minimax(board2D, false);
                board2D[i][j] = "";
                if(score < bestScore){
                    bestScore = score;
                    bestMove = {i, j};
                }
            }
        }
    }

    board2D[bestMove.i][bestMove.j] = "O"; //assigning bestMove to baord2D

    //to dispaly the played bestMove by the computer on screen
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            $[k].innerText = board2D[i][j];
            k += 1;
        }
    }
}

//minimax implementation
function minimax(position, maximizing){

    console.log(position);

    //if the game is over at that position, return the score based on who is wining
    if (checkForGameOver() === true){
        
        if(document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText[0] === "X"){
            return 1; //X (maximizing player) wins
        }
        else if(document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText[0] === "O"){
            return -1; //O (minimizing player) wins
        }
        else{
            return 0; // the game is a draw
        }
    }    
}


//function to check if game is over. But I think it can be written more easily.
function checkForGameOver(){
    var tempText = [];
    for(i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        tempText[i] = $[i-1].innerText;
    }
    if (tempText[1] === tempText[2] && tempText[2] === tempText[3] && tempText[1] !== ""){
        document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = tempText[1] + " Wins!!";
        return true;
    }
    else if (tempText[4] === tempText[5] && tempText[5] === tempText[6] && tempText[4] !== ""){
        document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = tempText[4] + " Wins!!";
        return true;
    }
    else if (tempText[7] === tempText[8] && tempText[8] === tempText[9] && tempText[7] !== ""){
        document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = tempText[7] + " Wins!!";
        return true;
    }
    else if (tempText[1] === tempText[4] && tempText[4] === tempText[7] && tempText[1] !== ""){
        document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = tempText[1] + " Wins!!";
        return true;
    }
    else if (tempText[2] === tempText[5] && tempText[5] === tempText[8] && tempText[2] !== ""){
        document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = tempText[2] + " Wins!!";
        return true;
    }
    else if (tempText[3] === tempText[6] && tempText[6] === tempText[9] && tempText[3] !== ""){
        document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = tempText[3] + " Wins!!";
        return true;
    }
    else if (tempText[1] === tempText[5] && tempText[5] === tempText[9] && tempText[1] !== ""){
        document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = tempText[1] + " Wins!!";
        return true;
    }
    else if (tempText[3] === tempText[5] && tempText[5] === tempText[7] && tempText[3] !== ""){
        document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = tempText[3] + " Wins!!";
        return true;
    }
    //if none of above, which is for win only, is true, check for draw which can be done by filtering the remaining blank squares. If no squares are lest, then game is a draw else the game isn't over yet.
    else{
        arrayOfBlankCharacters = tempText.filter(element => {
            return (element === "");
        });

        if (arrayOfBlankCharacters.length === 0){
            document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = "Game Drawn!!";
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

//a function that resets the board and win message.
function reset(){
    for(i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        $[i-1].innerText = "";
    }
    document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText = "";
}

//function to convert 1d array to 2d array => useful for computerTurn() function to access board in 2d view
function convertToTwoDimension(initialArray, rows, columns){
    var k = 0, finalArray = [];
    for(i = 0; i < initialArray.length/columns; i++){
        finalArray[i] = []; //state that each element of finalArray is also an array
        for(j = 0; j < initialArray.length/rows; j++){
            finalArray[i][j] = initialArray[k];
            k += 1;
        }
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap');

:root{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

*, *::after, *::before{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.description-header{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    line-height: 3rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.player-information{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.player-information > h3{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.player-information > h3 > span{
    color:brown;
}

.game-box-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
}

.tictactoe-box{
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr)/repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 0.5rem;
    background-color: black;
}

.reset-button-container{
    margin-top: 1rem;
    background: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.tictactoe-box > .box{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: context-menu
}

.reset-button-container > span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
}

.reset-button-container:hover{
    background-color: grey;
    cursor: context-menu;
}

.win-message{
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>TicTacToe</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tictactoe.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Tic_tac_toe.svg/1024px-Tic_tac_toe.svg.png">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-sclae=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="description-header">
            <h3>My TicTacToe Game</h3>
        </header>
        <div class="player-information">
            <h3>Player: "<span>X</span>"; Computer: "<span>O</span>"</h3>
            <h3>Player First</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="game-box-container">
            <div class="tictactoe-box">
                <div class="box box1"></div>
                <div class="box box2"></div>
                <div class="box box3"></div>
                <div class="box box4"></div>
                <div class="box box5"></div>
                <div class="box box6"></div>
                <div class="box box7"></div>
                <div class="box box8"></div>
                <div class="box box9"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="reset-button-container">
                <span>Reset</span>
            </div>
            <div class="win-message">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="usingMinimax.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem arises in the minimax(position, maximizing) function of the code as below. console.log(position) runs just fine, but because of the checkForGameOver() in the below function, it throws an error that board2D[i] is undefined which is unexpected because there is no any arguments passed in to the checkForGameOver() function. As soon as I remove the (checkForGameOver() === false) condition and run it, the computer makes a move for the first available spot which is as expected.

```
//minimax implementation
function minimax(position, maximizing){

    console.log(position);

    //if the game is over at that position, return the score based on who is wining
    if (checkForGameOver() === true){
        
        if(document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText[0] === "X"){
            return 1; //X (maximizing player) wins
        }
        else if(document.querySelector(".win-message").innerText[0] === "O"){
            return -1; //O (minimizing player) wins
        }
        else{
            return 0; // the game is a draw
        }
    }    
}
```

A function that doesn't take any variable as arguments just returns a boolean value, is somehow the cause of an error that the variable is undefined.

Comment: `board2D[i]` is in your `computerTurn` function, not your `checkForGameOver` function.  Also it is a bad idea to use `$` as a variable name for a node list of elements as `$` is often used to represent a JavaScript library object like JQuery. You should call your variables names that describe what they hold. `boxes` would be a better name for that. Also, instead of letters like `i` and `j`, use names that are more descriptive. This will help with your current issue as well.

Comment: Yes...its is in ```computerTurn``` function. That is why the error makes no sense to me. whenever ```checkForGameOver``` is called from inside the minimax it shows an error ```board2D[i]``` is undefined, but if I remove the call of ```checkForGameOver``` from the ```minimax```, it works fine without any error. I've no idea what is the relation of ```checkForGameOver``` with ```board2D[i]``` variable

Comment: The `else` condition in your `mainFunction` calls the `computerTurn` function and that's where your problem is, not in `checkForGameOver`.